# curl and thycotic secret server - at a loss

Tags: curl, authentication, token

First time poster.

I'm trying to do some automation with thycotic secret server and curl. But I can't for the life of me figure out why i can't make curl login.

I've done this multiple times with other csrf sites, but this one is making me scratch my head.

I've tried saving/posting all the fields, tokens and cookies but i can't even get an "login error"

I've taken the values below, saved and posted them with curl... (together with my user/pass of course). I'm posting them to /SecretServer/Login.aspx

---

```
ScriptManager_HiddenField
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
__VIEWSTATE
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
__SCROLLPOSITIONX
__SCROLLPOSITIONY
__EVENTVALIDATION
__RequestVerificationToken
LoginUserControl1$HasAddSecretPermissionControl
LoginUserControl1$UserNameTextBox
LoginUserControl1$PasswordTextBox
LoginUserControl1$DomainDropDownList
LoginUserControl1$LoginButton
LoginUserControl1$LoginDialog_IsCollapsed
```

---

What am I doing wrong? If you want to see the actual login page, i've setup a demo over http here:

```
http://h.ixx.io/SecretServer/
user: test
pass: password
```

Answer (score 3):

Secret Server has SOAP based Web Service API and that is where you will want to send your cURL calls too. That API is available by going to ***your-secret-server-url/webservices/sswebservice.asmx***

To make use of the API for automation you will want to first use the **Authenticate** call to get a Token. for example:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d        "username={NAME}&password={PASSWORD}&organization=&domain=" --url "http://your-secret-server-url/webservices/sswebservice.asmx/Authenticate";
```

With that Token, you can then use the rest of the API calls to look up Secrets, retrieve passwords, etc. With something like this:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "secretId={SECRET ID}&token={TOKEN}" --url "http://your-secret-server-url/webservices/sswebservice.asmx/GetSecretLegacy";
```

The rest of the cURL documentation can be found here: https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Accessing-Secret-Server-programmatically-Curl

And the API documentation can be found here:
https://updates.thycotic.net/secretserver/documents/SS_WebServicesGuide.pdf?when=02222016